# quaternion rotations and orientation at poles

Tags: matrix, three.js, trigonometry, quaternions

I'm working in threejs, and I'm struggling to find a method to avoid "pole switching" when orienting an object to a target.

Let’s say I have two moving Object3Ds, source and target, and I want source to rotate towards target. my function is:

```
const up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);

const p1 = source.getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3());
const p2 = target.getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3());
  
const vector_direction =
    new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(p2, p1).normalize();
const align_q =
    new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors( up, vector_direction );

source.quaternion.copy(align_q);
```

it works more or less like lookAt, and when the direction crosses north and south poles, the source object “spins” so it always faces up.

Is there any way to avoid this? I mean, given an initial object orientation, I’d simply like to rotate it towards the target, and if it crosses the poles, it lust keeps rotating and “facing upside down”.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi stmaccarelli- I think this is also known as gimbal lock. Some solutions are described in: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51410/how-to-avoid-gimbal-lock

Comment: thanks, just checked out